# Play audio songs from URL with AVAudioPlayer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, avaudioplayer

I want to play audio song from a URL, I implemented it successfully with `AVPlayer`, but at some point it is not working fine.

Can we play an audio song from a URL with `AVAudioPlayer`?

Which is better to play audio from a URL, providing all of the audio controls?

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not working fine"?

Answer (score 6):

Sure you can.

Objective-C:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"your string"];
AVPlayerItem *item = [[AVPlayerItem alloc]initWithURL:url];
AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithPlayerItem:item];
[player play];
```

Swift:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "yourURL")
let item = AVPlayerItem(URL: url)
let p = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
p.play()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @ njuri . Let me check out.

Comment: it does not play song . do you have any other way to do it ?